# what is "extends never" used for?

Tags: typescript

Here is an implementation of DeepReadonly (taken from [here](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/187), which is a solution to [this challenge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-M7bRbVPp-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-rwwj72MPN84vdEO1Zqt0OI4w62bpt21ToTK4HbJckgDxml0eiqwcF0ADKnQYQzjPaXTlB3mz0IvGqnrkiQXnYphECoehmHYdYuH4YR6jEdAwCiNYjzqPzEBQTBZKdRLnIoWhGFYcAOHsHhBFESRwBi0bOI6wAsh6Tx4oqsKxFLMtm-Lis2yrZEUWAQA)).

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = keyof T extends never
  ? T
  : { readonly [k in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[k]> };
```

What purpose is `extends never` serving here? I gather it's some kind of base case for the recursive type but I don't understand when we would hit it, and why it's necessary in the first place (since typescript apparently does allow some other types of self-referential type definitions without such base cases).

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

Comment: 'never' means it can be empty value. Extends is same as interface extends another interface or type

Comment: @jonrsharpe I do understand the basic idea behind conditional types, I just don't get how this particular example works.

Comment: @SteveTomlin when would `keyof T` be an empty value though?

Comment: It's not a great implementation, and where it works it kind of just happens to work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have all the same questions you do, I think.  The short answer is that I don't think it's a great implementation of `DeepReadonly<T>`, with no offense meant to whoever wrote it.

---

So `keyof T extends never` means that there are no known keys of the `T` type, since [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) produces a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of known keys, and [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is TypeScript's [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type), a type which has no values at all.  That means `keyof T extends never` behaves like this:

```
type Hmm<T> = keyof T extends never ? true : false
type X1 = Hmm<{ a: string }> // false, "a" is a known key
type X2 = Hmm<{}> // true, there are no known keys
type X3 = Hmm<object> // true, there are no known keys
type X4 = Hmm<string> // false, there are keys like "toUpperCase"
type X5 = Hmm<
  { a: string } | { b: string }
> // true, unions with no common keys have no known keys
```

Now that's not really a good way to implement `DeepReadonly<T>` where presumably you just want to stop recursing when you hit a primitive type.  But given the above output, that's not what `keyof T extends never` does.  For example:

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = keyof T extends never
    ? T
    : { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> };

type Z = DeepReadonly<{ a: string } | { b: string }> 
// type Z = {a: string} | {b: string}  OOPS

declare const z: Z;
if ("a" in z) {
    z.a = "" // no error, not readonly
}
```

Since we passed in a union, the compiler sees its keys as `never`, and suddenly we don't have `readonly` anywhere.  Oops.

---

The "right" definition of `DeepReadonly<T>` is probably just

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = 
  { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> };
```

[Mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) already "skip" primitives by returning the input, and they automatically distribute over union, so you don't need to check for these yourself:

```
type Look<T> = { [K in keyof T]: 123 };
type Y1 = Look<{ a: string }> // {a: 123}
type Y2 = Look<string> // string
type Y3 = Look<{ a: string } | { b: string }>
//  Look<{ a: string; }> | Look<{ b: string; }>
```

So with this version of `DeepReadonly` we get the right behavior for unions too:

```
type Z = DeepReadonly<{ a: string } | { b: string }> 
// type Z = DeepReadonly<{  a: string; }> | DeepReadonly<{ b: string; }>

declare const z: Z;
if ("a" in z) {
    z.a = "" // error! Cannot assign to 'a' because it is a read-only property
}
```

---

And if you ever *do* want to check for objects vs primitives, it's probably better to use [the `object` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type):

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends object ?
    { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> } : T;
```

This is similar to the type without the check: `T extends object ? ... : T` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) so it automatically splits unions up, processes them, and puts them back together:

```
type Z = DeepReadonly<{ a: string } | { b: string }>
// type Z = {  readonly a: string; } | { readonly b: string; }
```

This is the same as the previous type even though IntelliSense's quickinfo displays them differently.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VPpGM+7KvYgHNElGI0iploIZnJICm1rD1970pCM+DM1ns4CcnkpM4XJux32tvL5usNyrpuMz9tUzuFgXCsUS8MyuXmEhKlWiNXj7W6tAAQiQAGEQMBNSaQFAoNhPKQtQByECftsQkBTEs7gmhgGgqkGLAALTZEgMC6lQaAUBahA9n8AAybBsGIXQBqGkoRj4fD+EgmwPICsTJkgACa2yiBhWFVjWa4Np8uAHKR-yWrcSRUU8dGYdhHYYh2lFUYC-EMVmHYko25Jzg0RYTvR2FSWuXZCJUylVquxzqVaKG2tAcCIEgAByxqmRC0BQCy5COlMpAoGIICOB63E0OWLY4aIAzKKo6hICC4KQhM8okIGLZ4eGvSEcRS7TuELiRDJVh8Em7ljmmnnLox8kyWSbZ5d2hjFncpa5Kay6ztm9RdrJlXToVNXzta+n4EAA)

Comment: brilliant, thank you!
Your alternative definition doesn't work in the original challenge playground but I assume that's due to some idiosyncrasy in how the tests are implemented. (Edit - I added a link to the challenge playground in my question)

Comment: I guess they were trying to skip functions?  So then I'd write it as `type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends Function ? T :  { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> };` instead.  Of course use cases drive the definitions; even built-in utility types like `Readonly<T>` do weird things to functions (e.g.,  `Readonly<() => 22>` produces `{}` instead of `() => 22`), so for now I'd say the "right" definition of `DeepReadonly` is still probably the one I posted in the absence of specific use case requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
// type A = true
type A = ((...args: any) => any) extends object ? true : false

// above answer
type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends object ?
    { readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]> } : T;

type myObject = {
  a: () => 123
}

// type Result { readonly a: {} }
type Result = DeepReadonly<myObject>

// my answer
type DeepReadonly<T> = T extends never ? T : keyof T extends never ? T : {
  readonly[k in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[k]>
}
```