# Typescript Generics extending never

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The [Deep Readonly challenge](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00009-medium-deep-readonly/README.md) of the [TypeScript challenges repo](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges) has a very popular solution [here](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/187#issue-698088965):

```js
type DeepReadonly<T> = keyof T extends never
  ? T
  : { readonly [k in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[k]> };

// Usage 
type DeepResult = DeepReadonly<{ hello: 'world' }> 
//   ^? type DeepResult = { readonly hello: 'world'; }
```

Now, I'm fully aware of the solution's flaws as [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68693054/what-is-extends-never-used-for/68693367#68693367) but I just can't figure out how it works for the simple case scenario:

```js
type DeepResult2 = DeepReadonly<'world'>;
//   ^? type DeepResult2 = "world"
```

I mean how is this even possible? `keyof 'world' extends never ?` should return `{ readonly [k in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[k]> }` and not `T` (`world` in this case).

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. It kind of does. Assuming `keyof T` equals `world` then I'm still wondering why `type Res = 'world' extends never ? 'NEVER' : 'NO'` results to 'NO' instead of 'NEVER'. I mean I understand why `world` is not `never` but `DeepReadonly` works the "other way around".

Comment: only `never` extends `never`. This will result in the false branch for every type except `never`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "works the other way around"

Comment: `type DeepReadonly<T> = keyof T extends never ? T : { readonly [k in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[k]> };`. Suppose I do `DeepReadonly<'hi'>` which simply results to `'hi'`. If I inline the values we get: `keyof 'hi' extends never ? 'hi' : { readonly [k in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[k]> };`. Now the result is `'hi'` even though `'hi'` does not extend `never`. Does that make sense?

Comment: The linked answer states that using a mapped type over a primitive returns the primitive itself

Comment: so does this mean that this part of the condition `{ readonly [k in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[k]> };` returns `hi`?

Comment: yes, again it is clearly in the linked answer: "So what happens when `T` is a primitive type like `string`?  The pull request says "we simply produce that primitive type"."